# Write a function that replaces the character c to '*'

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

Condition: Function containing character c and string xs, where all c's are replaced by '*'.

`

```
zensiert :: [Char] -> String
zensiert c (x:xs) 
    | x == c = x == '*'
    | otherwise = zensiert c (x:xs)
```

`
The map function and list generators are prohibited. Example: zensiert 'l' ''Rolls a ball around the corner and falls down.'' returns:''Ro**s a ba** **around the corner and fa**s down.''

Because of the example is was thinking that is at the beginning a list in a char that leads to a string, but it didn ´ t work. Because of that I would be very conceivable, if someone would look over there times

Now I tried so:

```
zensiert :: [Char] -> String                               
zensiert (x:xs) = if x == 'c' then ('*' : zensiert xs) else (x : zensiert xs)
```

But there is the problem, if i give zensiert 'l' "Hello", the terminal says: Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> t’ with actual type ‘[Char]’

Comment: You want `Char`, not `[Char]`, in the signature.

Comment: It also looks like you were trying to make `x == '*'` replace the value of `x` in the string. Haskell doesn't have assignments, and `==` wouldn't be the assignment operator if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the type signature should be

```
zensiert :: Char -> String -> String
```

You'll take a character and a string as arguments, and return a new string.

`==` is not an assignment operator, even if Haskell *did* have assignments. Your second definition would be fine (for replacing hard-coded `'c'`s, anyway), except you don't define it for the empty string the recursive call will eventually receive, and you incorrectly call it with a `Char` argument it won't use.

The correct definition takes a `Char` argument and uses that instead of the `Char` literal `'c'`.

```
zensiert :: Char -> String -> String
zensiert _ [] = []
zensiert c (x:xs) = if x == c then ('*' : zensiert xs) else (x : zensiert xs)
```

---

A simpler approach would be to use `map` to apply a function that replaces `'c'` with `'*'` to a list, whether it is empty or not.

```
zensiert c xs = map (\x -> if x == c then '*' else x) xs
```

or

```
zensiert c xs = map f xs
    where f 'c' = '*'
          f x = x
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it, thank you very very much, i have it, but i did the signatur wrong, nice

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are defining recursive functions, you need at least one base case that exists the recursion, and at least one case that calls the function recursively in a way that converges on the base case.

If you're dealing with strings, the base case is often an empty string, and we converge the making the input string closer to an empty string.

Replacing any character with `'*'` in an empty string gives us just an empty string, so the base case is simple. For the update case, we just have to decide what to append to recursively calling the function on the "tail" of the string.

```
ghci> :{
ghci| subChar _ "" = ""
ghci| subChar c (x:xs) 
ghci|   | c == x    = '*' : subChar c xs
ghci|   | otherwise =  x  : subChar c xs
ghci| :}
ghci> subChar 'l' "world"
"wor*d"
ghci>
```